# how to add the checkbox to the datagridview from coding

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, datatable, windows-forms-designer

how to add the `checkbox` to the `datagridview` from coding in windows form.

i have a `datatable` with one column as `value=true;`
and in another `datatable` i had settings for that column as `value='Checkbox'`

so if my value is true and `checkbox` is there the default datatable `value` cell has to be replaced with `checkbox` selected true. in that way

if the value is true by default it should be checked in that checkbox..

Comment: methinks stackoverflow has a problem...

Comment: You've edited the question and now you're asking another thing (which isn't clear, at least for me). If you have another question, ask it separately, because people who might know how to answer that won't read this question (which has the title for the old question)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you meant to add a column with checkboxes:

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
checkColumn.Name = "X";
checkColumn.HeaderText = "X";
checkColumn.Width = 50;
checkColumn.ReadOnly = false;
checkColumn.FillWeight = 10; //if the datagridview is resized (on form resize) the checkbox won't take up too much; value is relative to the other columns' fill values
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(checkColumn);
```

Answer (score 9):

I think the easiest way to add Checkbox column in datagrid view is from the UI

```
              Step1 : Select the dataGrid at the UI
              Step2: Select Edit Column
              Step3: Click on the column name in edit Columns Window
              Step4:Select column type = "DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn"
              Step5: click ok
```

Attached a snaphot
[image]

Comment: I think this is the best way!

Comment: I don't get why it's the best way. It's the best way only if your datagrid is not linked to some datasource.

Answer (score 4):

For these kind of questions you can just add the control through the designer and see what Visual Studio did in the code behind file.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you mean how to add a checkbox column to a `DataGridView` dynamically:

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
... // set properties as needed here
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
```

Answer (score 0):

you may also need to set the `TrueValue` and `FalseValue`

```
officeCheckBoxColumn.TrueValue = 1;
officeCheckBoxColumn.FalseValue = 0;
```

I am wondering if there is way to check all or uncheck all `CheckBox` by default?